# Is it possible to get a reference to an Android Dialog from one of its children?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, android-dialog

I'm using a FragmentActivity with a FragmentStatePagerAdapter. In my fragments, I set click listeners on some views that respond by showing a Dialog. The Dialog layout is supplied via an XML layout resource, and some buttons in this layout use the onClick property to fire off a method in the FragmentActivity. And that works fine, the method gets called correctly when the buttons are clicked.

But I'd like to know how to get hold of a reference to the Dialog when the onClick method is called. All I have is the view (button) that was clicked, which is a child of the Dialog's layout. I actually just want to dismiss the dialog. And I'd really prefer not to have to make the Dialog some sort of global, static singleton or whatever, there must be a cleaner way. I'll try to illustrate it with some code:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    ...
    ...
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(...) {
        ...
        dialogTrigger.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View src) {
                MyDialog dialog = new MyDialog(src.getContext());
                dialog.show();
            }
        });
    ...
}

public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    ...
    public void doIt(View src) {
        // dialog ref ???
    }
    ...
}
```

...and the Dialog layout XML:

```
<GridLayout ...>

    <Button
        ... 
        android:onClick="doIt" />
...
etc.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not the way you are doing it, because the dialog only exists once clicked. If however you move the declaration to a member variable, yes (as below)

```
 public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    private MyDialog dialog;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(...) {
        ...
        dialogTrigger.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View src) {
                dialog = new MyDialog(src.getContext());
                dialog.show();
           }
        });
        ...

       protected MyDialog getDialog() {
           return dialog.
       }
   }

   public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity {

   public void doIt(View src) {
      //TODO: seems you want to do this too (?):  dialogTrigger.callOnClick();
      //EDIT: oops i missed the following the first time
      MyDialog dialog = ((MyFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.my_fragment)).getDialog()
      ....
   }
```

There are better ways to handle such a situation though

Comment: Are you suggesting that I make the dialog static and include a static class method for retrieving the dialog ref? I tried that there, and it does work, but I'm concerned about the lifecycle. Should I be?. As for the TODO, the doIt method is not called by me. It's called by the framework as a result of a view inside the Dialog being clicked. So in doIt, I just want to close the dialog and then do some other stuff.

Comment: Yes I know its called from the XML, that's why I suggested it as it looked like you cant be sure dialogTrigger is clicked. If it should already be open just make sure you do a null check to be safe

Comment: Ok, well it's definitely being called, logging shows that much anyway.

Comment: I definitely prefer what you're suggesting, but I'm uncertain about how to go about it. My fragments don't have IDs. I'm using a ViewPager and FragmentStatePagerAdapter because the number of fragments is unknown and potentially large. I have an XML layout file with a RelativeLayout at the root, and this is inflated and used as the contents of each fragment. So, I'm not sure exactly what it is that I should reference? I suppose what I need is the currently active fragment...

Comment: It looks like getting the currently active fragment with a ViewPager and FragmentStatePagerAdapter is not straightforward, but I'm also wondering if the static approach is worthwhile. It's simple, it works and there's actually no reason why I would want a situation where multiple fragment instances have refs to different dialog instances. I suppose the only concern is if a fragment is resumed and still carries a ref to a stale dialog...

Comment: Did this solve your problem in the end? can you accept it, or add another answer and close the question so it's off of the android unanswered list, thanks

Comment: This did help, sorry for the delay.